# How to use grep to search for a file anywhere

Tags: grep

I'm finding that a script is getting started twice, so I want to search for the script name in any file anywhere, to see where its getting called.

So I did this...

```
cd /
sudo grep -r autostart *
```

But that gives me the error..

```
boot/System.map-3.5.0-23-generic:c1490f90 t autostart_arrays
grep: dev/vsock: Invalid argument
```

Comment: `sudo grep -rl autostart /*`. Does that work?

Answer (score 3):

This is not an error. Grep just reported its failure to search through a special file (probably a socket), and was already working on the next. If you don't want to see grep's error messages, you can send them to the bitbucket:

```
fgrep -r autostart * 2> /dev/null
```

Note that **fgrep** will likely be much faster in your case because you are searching for a string, not for a regular expression.

Contrary to what you it looked like, grep hadn't crashed. Technically, it wasn't hung either. Maybe it was searching `/dev/random` for the string. Eventually it would find  it there, though this might take an astronomical amount of time. Sadly, soon after grep *would* have found the string in `/dev/random`, it would encounter `/dev/zero` where it would certainly spend an infinity of time looking for the string. Logically therefore, your command was guaranteed to not terminate.

If you wish to prevent `fgrep` from searching special files, combine it with `find`:

```
find / -type f -exec fgrep -l autostart {} \;
```

And since you're looking for a script, skipping all all non-executables on the file system will save a lot of time:

```
find / -type f -executable -exec fgrep -l autostart {} \;
```

In fact, I would focus my search first on the usual suspects:

```
find {,/usr}/{,s}bin /etc -type f -executable -exec fgrep -l autostart {} \;
```

Particularly so if you have some remote file systems mounted, which grep would dutifully search as well.

Comment: Thanks. Are you saying that it hadnt crashed but had just printed out a message and was continuing to search in the background?

Comment: Thanks, I tried `find / -type x -exec fgrep -l autostart {} \;` but it came back with `find: Unknown argument to -type: x`

Comment: also should I add `sudo` before these commands?

Comment: No, grep didn't technically crash. It was guaranteed to run forever though. Added the explanation for this to the answer. You should need to `sudo` these commands only if the string could be in a non-world-readable (and therefore non-world-executable) file.